# Cakephp calculate rank of posts by number of comments

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a basic post and comments cakephp application.

I want to show a table with a column that shows rank of posts by number of comments.

I'd settle for a percentage of total comments by post.

Where in cakephp would I do this?  Where would I do count of comments by post divided by total count of all comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where:** You do it in the model. That's [good practice](http://bitfluxx.com/2008/01/23/cakephp-best-practices-fat-models-and-skinny-controllers.html).

**How:** I see two valid methods (I mean, there's tons of alternatives, but these are the easiest and don't repeat code everywhere)

1. Use [Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html). In your model do something like

   ```
   public $virtualFields = array(
       'rank' => '/*query*/'  //sql query that get's the number you want
   );
   ```

   That will add a field (virtual, is not in the DB) everytime you do a find() of that model
2. Create your own function in the model an call it whenever you want

   ```
   public getRank($postID) {
       $post = $this->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$postID);
       $rank = /*do the calculation you want*/
       return $rank;
   }
   ```

   You call that function from the controllers like find() or save() or any other

   ```
   $this->Post->getRank($id);
   ```

   If by any reason you want to have this rank *everytime* you call a Post, then in the [afterFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html) method of that post, add a call to that function:

   ```
   public afterFind(array $results, boolean $primary = false) {
         parent::afterFind($results, $primary);
         foreach ($results as $i=>$result) {
              $results[$i]['rank'] = $this->getRank($result['id']);
         }
         return $results;
   }
   ```

   I didn't test the *afterFind* function. So change it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for detail.  I have vague conceptual appreciation for separating model and controller functionality and making model 'fat' and controller 'skinny'. So far, all of my cakephp apps have 'fat' controllers and 'skinny' models.  But your examples do give me some more idea of what can go into model.  Thanks.

Comment: It happened to me too. I only got a good appreciation for 'fat' models when I realized I had to repeat the same code everywhere. I guess it comes with practice :)

Comment: I like the emphasis on minimization of repeating code (DRY = don't repeat yourself) .. which appears to be the real purpose of "fat" models vs "fat" controllers. Thanks again!